# Every element rerenders with react using redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abby_io/g35wL3r1/4/)

```
var gridWidth = 15;
var gridHeight = 15;

var grid = [];
for(var y=0; y<gridHeight; y++) {
    grid.push([]);
    for(var x=0; x<gridWidth; x++) {
        grid[y][x] = {c:0};
    }
}

var reducer = function(state = grid, action) {
  let newState = clone(state);
  if(action.type==='CC') {
    newState[action.payload.y][action.payload.x].c = action.payload.c;
  }
  return newState;
}
var store = Redux.createStore(reducer);

var colours = ['black', 'grey'];
var Provider = ReactRedux.Provider;
var connect = ReactRedux.connect;
var map = function(state) {
    return {grid:state};
}

var Box = React.createClass({
    width: 15,
    handleClick: function(x, y) {
        this.props.dispatch({type:'CC', payload: {c:1, x:x, y:y}});
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log('boxrender')
        var pos = {
          top: this.props.y * this.width,
          left: this.props.x * this.width,
          width: this.width,
          height: this.width,
          background: this.props.colours[this.props.box.c]
        }
        return <div className="box" style={pos} onMouseOver={() => this.handleClick(this.props.x, this.props.y)}></div>
    }
});
var ConnectedBox = connect(map)(Box);

var Grid = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    console.log('grid render')
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.grid.map((row, y) => {
          return row.map((box, x) => {
            return <ConnectedBox key={'x'+x+'y'+y} box={box} x={x} y={y} colours={this.props.colours} />;
          })
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
});
var ConnectedGrid = connect(map)(Grid);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedGrid colours={colours} />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

I have a large grid that I want to be able to 'colour in' on mouseover, using redux to make the changes, however even though only one box object is being changed, react is re-rendering every box each time one changes and I don't know why? It's making it super slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Optimized: https://jsfiddle.net/p6z5veo6/5/

---

**Basic perf rules for React**

- Use `React.PureComponent` or `React.Component` with custom `shouldComponentUpdate`
- Pass only needed slice of the store to your components
- Avoid re-rendering if props or state has not changed
- Avoid creating new instances of objects and binding functions on each render (very often happens when `() => {}` is pass to `onClick` etc.)

**What I did and why**

- Implemented custom `shouldComponentUpdate` for `Grid` and `Box` components

  ```
  class Box extends React.Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
      return nextProps.colour !== this.props.colour;
    }

  // ...

  class Grid extends React.Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
      return false;
    }
  ```
- In this case `Grid` component doesn't have to be re-rendered every time when store is updated because we want to re-render only specific `Box` component so we use `Grid` only for initial rendering and pass only relevant data from the store to `Box`

  ```
  const ConnectedBox = connect((store, { x, y }) => ({
    colour: store[y][x].c
  }))(Box);
  ```
- Implemented simpler version of your reducer, just update main reference and object which contain new colour

  ```
  var reducer = (state = grid, action) => {
    if (action.type === "CC") {
      const { x, y, c } = action.payload;

      const newState = [...state];
      newState[y][x] = { c };

      return newState;
    }

    return state;
  };
  ```
- Bind `handleClick` in costructor

  ```
  class Box extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.width = 15;
      this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
  ```

Very similar *project* was implemented and described in the article: [An artificial example where MobX really shines and Redux is not really suited for it](https://hackernoon.com/an-artificial-example-where-mobx-really-shines-and-redux-is-not-really-suited-for-it-1a58313c0c70).

Repository of the project from article is also [available on github](https://github.com/dtinth/pixelpaint). You can [read article](https://hackernoon.com/an-artificial-example-where-mobx-really-shines-and-redux-is-not-really-suited-for-it-1a58313c0c70), [check repo](https://github.com/dtinth/pixelpaint) and [this pull request](https://github.com/dtinth/pixelpaint/pull/1) so you can learn how eventually could you more improve your code because the problem is with the data structure (array) that you decided to use to store in redux.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer, this is great and has given me loads to think about and new approaches to try. Your fiddle is much faster and I can see it rendering only the square; it still inevitably slows down if i bump the grid up to something more like 150x250, but I'll keep trying!

Comment: Check also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782249/can-a-react-redux-app-really-scale-as-well-as-say-backbone-even-with-reselect/34788570#34788570 which suggests two interesting solutions: custom `connect` HOC and using different data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You're rendering a list of lists, try wrapping each inner list in a `div` so it can get a proper `key`:

```
{
  this.props.grid.map((row, y) => 
    <div key={y}>
      {
        row.map((box, x) => 
          <ConnectedBox key={'x'+x+'y'+y} box={box} x={x} y={y} colours={this.props.colours} />)
      }
    </div>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what's causing it at a glance, but if you just need a quick fix you can add a `shouldComponentUpdate` to prevent it from rendering unless the `box.c` changes:

```
var Box = React.createClass({
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return this.props.box.c !== nextProps.box.c;
  },
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5c21yw3j/